# How to create singleton resource in feathers with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I need a resource that wouldn't be a collection but single item instead. I don't see anything about customizing mongoose service in that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can return anything from your `find` method, it does not have to be a collection. So to get an object for e.g. `/singleton` you can just do something like:

```
app.use('/singleton', {
  find: function(params) {
    return Promise.resolve({
      test: 'data'
    });
  }
});
```

This will of course also work via a websocket `socket.emit('singleton::find')`. For the Mongoose service there are two options:

### 1) Extending

Extend the service and then call it with a single object like this:

```
const MongooseService = require('feathers-mongoose').Service;

class SingletonService extends MongooseService {
  find(params) {
    return super.find(params).then(data => data[0]);
  }
}

app.use('/singleton', new SingletonService({
  Model: Todo,
  name: 'todo'
}));
```

### 2) Hooks

Potentially even nicer with [feathers-hooks](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-hooks), register an `after` hook that retrieves the singleton item from the collection originally requested:

```
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');

app.configure(hooks())
  .use('/singleton', mongooseService('todo', Todo));

app.service('singleton').hooks({
  after: {
    find(hook) {
      const firstItem = hook.result[0];
      hook.result = firstItem;
    }
  }
});
```